# Why does Spark exit with exitCode: 16?

Tags: apache-spark

I am using Spark 2.0.0 with Hadoop 2.7 and use the yarn-cluster mode. Every time, I get the following error:

```
17/01/04 11:18:04 INFO spark.SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
17/01/04 11:18:04 INFO yarn.ApplicationMaster: Final app status: FAILED, exitCode: 16, (reason: Shutdown hook called before final status was reported.)
17/01/04 11:18:04 INFO util.ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
17/01/04 11:18:04 INFO util.ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/hadoop-hduser/nm-local-dir/usercache/harry/appcache/application_1475261544699_0833/spark-42e40ac3-279f-4c3f-ab27-9999d20069b8
17/01/04 11:18:04 INFO spark.SparkContext: SparkContext already stopped.
```

However, I do get the correct printed output. 
The same code works fine in Spark 1.4.0-Hadoop 2.4.0 where I do not see any exit codes.

Comment: Do you have `System.exit(0)` in your code?

Comment: So, did you check the YARN logs for that `application_xxxxxxxx_xxxx` to understand what the "yarn.ApplicationMaster" was complaining about?

Comment: @ThiagoBaldim: I dont believe so, besides it worked in Spark 1.4 as I mentioned before.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter: Yes, three of us looked into it, and we didn't find any issue besides the one mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This issue **.sparkStaging not cleaned if application exited incorrectly** https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-17340 started after Spark 1.4 (Affects Version/s: 1.5.2, 1.6.1, 2.0.0)

The issue is: When running Spark (yarn,cluster mode) and killing application
.sparkStaging is not cleaned.

When this issue happened exitCode 16 raised in Spark 2.0.X

```
ERROR ApplicationMaster: RECEIVED SIGNAL TERM
INFO ApplicationMaster: Final app status: FAILED, exitCode: 16, (reason: Shutdown hook called before final status was reported.)
```

Is it possible that in your code, something is killing the application?
If so - it shouldn't be seen in Spark 1.4, but should be seen in Spark 2.0.0

Please search your code for "exit" (as if you have such in your code, the error won't be shown in Spark 1.4, but will in Spark 2.0.0)

Comment: Thiago Baldim and Yaron are correct. I noticed that spark/resource-managers/yarn/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/deploy/yarn/ApplicationMaster.scala was changed in Spark 2.0 and it now errors on "exit". We had `Sys.exit(0)` rather than `System.exit(0)` and missed searching it before.

Comment: @Yaron I understood that if I put exit in code this error is coming. Suppose I have a scenario where I have to stop application successfully based on condition, I am giving sparkSession.stop followed by System.exit(0). Still application is giving above mentioned message and application status is FAILED. How can I stop my application with status as SUCCESS in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like excess memory is used by JVM, try adding the property

`yarn.nodemanager.vmem-check-enabled` to **false** in your yarn-site.xml

[Reference](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/YARN-4714)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It seems now that we had `Sys.exit(0)` that led to the issue. If it's otherwise I'll try your workaround.